# gwt-query - nested draggable propagation

Tags: gwt, draggable, event-propagation, gwtquery

I've written the following code:

```
HorizontalPanel draggable = new HorizontalPanel();
Function startDragParent = new Function () {
    @Override
    public boolean f (Event e) {
    // some code here...
    return false;
}
};
Function dragParent = new Function () {
    @Override
    public boolean f (Event e) {
    // some code here...
    return false;
}
};
Function stopDragParent = new Function () {
    @Override
    public boolean f (Event e) {
    // some code here...
    return false;
}
};
$(draggable).as(Ui).draggable()
    .bind(Draggable.Event.start, startDragParent);
    .bind(Draggable.Event.drag, dragParent);
    .bind(Draggable.Event.stop, stopDragParent);

HorizontalPanel childDraggable = new HorizontalPanel();
Function dragChild = new Function () {
    @Override
    public boolean f (Event e) {
    // some code here...
    return false;
}
};
$(childDraggable).as(Ui).draggable().bind(Draggable.Event.drag, dragChild);

// finally I add one element inside another
draggable.add(childDraggable);
```

My problems start when I start dragging the inner element around, then draggable (parent of childDraggable) start dragging too (**only in IE8 and, I guess, in previous versions**). I would like preventing this kind of event propagation, i.e. I would like dragging the innerElement without dragging its parent.

I've tryied *stopPropagation* and *preventDefault* but it was no good. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which versions of gwt, gwtquery and gwt-draggable are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.4 for GWT, gwt-query 1.1.0 and release 146 of gwt-query-ui. But I'm afraid changing versions would not be an option. I guess it could be something concerning to jquery use in IE8, but it's only a feeling.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you were using gwtquery + gwtquery-dnd (both written in java and dont need external js). Your setup is pretty much complicated since Gwtquery-ui is a wrapper for the jquery-ui.js which as well needs jquery.js. Unfortunately I cannot help since I dont use this plugin. Maybe you could get some help from jsquery-ui lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stopPropagation doesn't work on IE, you should use something like cancelBubble in the following manner:

```
function stop(e) {
    // feature check (in IE this will be undefined) 
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        // standards compliant browser
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        // dreadful IE 
        e.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
```